# Same MD5 hash value but different input using hash('md5')

Tags: php, cryptography, md5, exploit

I know that there is some case 2 different strings can have same MD5 hash but when I try with PHP it still become 2 different hash. So is there any string that have same MD5 hash in PHP if I use `hash('md5', $blablabla)`?

Comment: Do you have an actual programming question? Otherwise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can two different strings generate the same MD5 hash code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756004/can-two-different-strings-generate-the-same-md5-hash-code)

Comment: In terms of security this might interest you as well: https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/magic-hashes/
It shows how some hashes can be bypassed when you aren't using a strict comparison in php.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple.

Indeed MD5 is considered as weak today and it is possible to [find a collision](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Tunnels-in-Hash-Functions%3A-MD5-Collisions-Within-a-Kl%C3%ADma/303a13faac4a76c2e249fcd9587257f276da1a02) (another input giving the same hash) under a minute.

Regardless that you have to compute the inputs, just guessing won't work. MD5 produces 128 bit output, so with random guessing will find collision with probability 1/(2^128)   (almost impossible)