# Is a hash result ever the same as the source value?

Tags: hash, cryptography, hash-collision, hash-code-uniqueness

This is more of a cryptography theory question, but is it possible that the result of a hash algorithm will ever be the same value as the source? For example, say I have a string:

```
baf34551fecb48acc3da868eb85e1b6dac9de356
```

If I get the SHA1 hash on it, the result is:

```
4d2f72adbafddfe49a726990a1bcb8d34d3da162
```

In theory, is there ever a case where these two values would match? I'm not asking about SHA1 specifically here - it's just my example. I'm just wondering if hashing algorithms are built in such a way as to prevent this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235785/is-there-an-md5-fixed-point-where-md5x-x

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340524/is-there-any-x-for-which-sha1x-equals-x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it would depend on the hashing algorithm - but I'd be surprised to see anything explicitly prevent this. After all, it really shouldn't matter.

I suspect it's very unlikely to happen, of course (for cryptographic hashes)... but even if it does, that shouldn't cause a problem.

For non-crypto hashes (used in hash tables etc) it would be perfectly reasonable to return the source value in some cases. For example, in Java, `Integer.hashCode()` just returns the embedded value.

Comment: it'd be funny if someone could find an example!

Comment: In .NET Int32.GetHashCode also returns the int value.

Comment: Worst case, the chances of a hash returning the input would be the same as two inputs returning the same hash - i.e. your chances of winning the lottery are much much higher.

Comment: Evernoob: get to it! Let me know how you're getting on after the first few trillion millenia!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, the Python hashing algorithm for integers returns the value of the integer.  So hash(1) == 1.

Answer (score 4):

Given a good hashing algorithm, one that returns a seemingly random output, I believe there should be on average one input that gives itself as the output.  Let's say the hash can give N possible outputs.  That means there are N possible inputs for which this is possible.  For each of those, the odds of the output matching the input is 1/N, so there the expected number of fixed points is N*1/N, or 1.

Answer (score 2):

A hash function *might* be defined to avoid ‘fixed points’ where hash(x)==x, but your hash-quine differs a little in that you're taking the string representation in hex of the hash rather than the raw binary. It would, I think, be infeasible to design a hash that could frustrate that, and it's mathematically less interesting since it depends on the arbitrary mapping of 0-F to ASCII character codes.

See [Is there an MD5 Fixed Point where md5(x) == x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235785/is-there-an-md5-fixed-point-where-md5x-x) for a discussion about fixed points in MD5. The probability calculation would be equally true for hex hash-quines and any other hash function with 128 bits of output.

Comment: I hadn't considered that I was hashing a string representation - in my question, I meant to refer to the hex value. I guess my question could really be phrased as "If I hash a password, is there ever a chance that the result is actually the password itself?"

Comment: Unless your password is exactly the length of the hash function's output, no. :)