# How can I prevent Git from adding carriage returns even with core.autocrlf=true?

Tags: git, line-endings

I'm working on a cross-platform repository and our default line ending for the repo is LF. A Windows developer just pushed a commit that changed all line endings in every file to CRLF. I would like all of our developers to be able to work with their systems' native line endings locally and commit as LF, which if I understand correctly should be handled by setting `core.autocrlf=true` in the Git configuration.

This developer has a local git config with `core.autocrlf=true` and a global config with no entry for autocrlf. Why would these line endings still be changed?

Comment: Did he add a .gitattributes file or change an existing one? Settings in there can affect everyone and override config. See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: @JamesWorld No, there's no .gitattributes file for the repository and he didn't add one either

Answer (score 2):

First, let's make a few background notes:

1. Everyone has their own *repository*.  The configuration for a repository is per-copy: it's not shared across all repositories.

   For this reason and others, it may be wise to avoid `core.autocrlf`.  Instead, using a `.gitattributes` *file*, which goes into each commit, may make more sense.  We'll see more about this in a bit.
2. You literally can't change what anyone else pushes.  They're pushing *commits* and no part of any commit can ever be changed.  Once that commit is made, that's it for that commit.  If there is some major problem with that commit, don't let it into *your* repository (their repository is *theirs*, so that's their problem to deal with).

   If it already got into your repository, don't use it, and do what you can to eject it if that's not too painful.  Have someone (yourself or him) copy the bad commit to a new and improved replacement, and use that instead.

   In any case, note that it's the *commits* that matter, and the *commits* that get shared from one repository to another.  We'll see more about this in a moment.
3. You also cannot control the commits that someone else makes.  That's up to *them* to do.
4. What *goes into these commits* is not necessarily the same as what *you or they work with*.  This is what `core.autocrlf` and the other controls in `.gitattributes` are about.

Since everything else has been fine so far, you literally don't *need* to make any changes yourself.  If you do make any changes, that's just to make things easier for your Windows guys.

> This developer has a local git config with `core.autocrlf=true` and a global config with no entry for autocrlf.  Why would these line endings still be changed?

We don't and can't know; only he (the guy with the repository, on his Windows system) can find out.  Given what you've said so far, this probably should not have happened at all, but given that it did, let's consider doing something other than using `core.autocrlf`.

#### Commits and branch names

Let's talk a bit about commits: what they are, semi-precisely, and how we use them and exchange them from one repository to another.  We've already mentioned that no commit can ever be changed.  This will explain *why*.  Note that the commits are stored as "objects"—one of four kinds of objects, actually—in the main repository database.  (The commit object itself requires multiple supporting objects to be useful; we'll just kind of skip over this stuff as it's mostly irrelevant here, but it's why three of the four kinds of objects exist.)

First, each commit is numbered.  These numbers aren't simple or sequential: they *look* random.  They get expressed as big ugly hash IDs.  The hash ID of some commit is unique to that one particular commit.  It's actually a cryptographic checksum of the *contents* of that commit: every bit of every byte of the internal Git object that makes up that commit.  This is why you can't change any of it: if you take a commit out of the database, fiddle with it and change some bits, and put that back, what you get is a *new* commit, with a new and different number.  The old commit still exists.  Each object will remain in the database as long as it is being used.<sup>1</sup>

What each commit *stores* comes in two parts:

- First, there's a *full snapshot of every file*.  These are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format, that only Git can read, and literally nothing can write.  (These are tree and blob objects, referred-to by the commit object, read-only but but shareable.)
- Second, there's a bunch of *metadata:* information about the commit itself, such as who made it, when, and why (their log message).  To this commit data—some of which comes from the user, such as the log message—Git adds its own key item or items: the raw hash ID of the *parent* of the commit, or, for a merge commit, the parents, plural.  These are commits that already exist at the time the new commit is being written.

The result is a Directed Acyclic Graph<sup>2</sup> of commits, where each commit points *backwards* to some earlier commit(s).  This allows branch names to work by identifying only the *last* that we wish to call part of some branch.  We can draw these like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

These two branch names allow us not to have to remember the hash IDs of the two *last* commits `J` and `L` in the two branches.  Note that commits up through `H`, which may well be the *last* commit on another branch (`main` or `master` perhaps), are on both of these two branches: they are *shared*.

Because each commit's frozen snapshot is also share-able on a file-by-file basis, it's OK that each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file.  Any files in commit `H` that are identical in commits `I`, `J`, `K`, and `L` are literally shared.  Only files that have different content in different commits require new snapshots.<sup>3</sup>

All of this, however, means one other thing as well: it's literally impossible to work on or with the files that are *inside* commits.  So, when using Git, you don't.  You work instead on *copies* of the committed files.  These copies are not actually *in* the repository at all.  Git extracts the commits to a separate directory (or "folder" if you prefer that term), where the files you work on are *yours*.  Git calls this working area your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

---

<sup>1</sup>For many commits, that's forever, or as long as the repository itself is around anyway.  It can be hard to be rid of unwanted commits, though `git reset` is one way to get there, sometimes, again with a lot of technical caveats.

<sup>2</sup>Note that we have no idea what the hash ID will be for some *future* commit, making it difficult or impossible to produce a loop.  The hash ID of a future commit depends on exactly what will be in it, including (a) a future timestamp and (b) the hash ID of *this* commit, if this commit is to be in the future commit's past.  We don't even know what the future timestamp will be, much less what the hash ID of *this* commit will be.  A fixed point in the hash function would be handy (see, e.g., [Sha-1 hash fixed point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935717/sha-1-hash-fixed-point)) but insufficient.

<sup>3</sup>Even then, if the different snapshots are similar, Git will (usually, and usually later) *pack* the underlying file-content objects, which will use [delta compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) to store most of the shared contents just once.  This means that the storage needed for the object database remains relatively small.

---

#### That's two copies of each file, but there is a third

Consider what happens when you check out some particular commit.  You run:

```
git checkout somebranch
```

and Git finds the commit that the name `somebranch` selects, e.g., commit `J` or `L` from `branch1` or `branch2` in the diagram above.  Git now arranges for the named branch to be the *current branch* and the selected commit to be the *current commit*.  Git copies all the files *out* of the chosen commit, into your working tree.  There are now two copies of each committed file, e.g., the committed copy of `README.md` *plus* the working tree copy of `README.md`.

The only copy you can see and work on/with is the one in your work-tree.  These two copies are all that are, in any sort of strict sense, necessary.  Other version control systems stop at these two copies.  But Git isn't these other version control systems.  Git inserts a *third* copy of each file, in between the current commit copy and your work-tree copy.

This third copy is mostly invisible.  It doesn't show up in ordinary directory listings.  In fact, it isn't even a full *copy*, at most times and in most senses.  That's because Git keeps it in the compressed and de-duplicated format it would have if it were in a commit:

- If it *is* in some existing commit, it's already there, in the internal database of objects, and Git is just sharing it.  That's the case initially for *every* file from the current commit.  So this third copy takes no extra space, or almost none.
- But suppose you modify a work-tree file.  Git's internal extra copy is not yet changed in any way.  You must now run `git add` on the updated file.  Git will now read, compress, and de-duplicate the result.  If there's one in some commit, Git will share *that* one.  If not, Git will have a copy ready to go into a new commit.<sup>4</sup>

This explains why you always have to `git add` files: what you're doing is copying the new version into the new ready-to-go commit.  This third copy of every file, then, is, in a sense, your *proposed next commit*.  It's in the de-duplicated *format*, just as it would be in a commit.  What's different from it being in a commit is that you can *replace* it, without changing the commit itself.

Git calls this storage area, holding the proposed next commit, by three different names: it is the *index*—an inoffensive, but also kind of meaningless, term—or the *staging area*, reflecting how it's used; or, rarely these days, Git calls it the *cache*, referring to how it makes Git go faster, by remembering things about ("indexing") your working tree.  During a conflicted merge, Git expands the index, so that it's no longer just a staging cache; here the term *index* really takes on a more useful role.  It's also the most general form so it's the one I tend to use.  But all three words refer to this same thing, which most of the time, holds your proposed *next* commit.

When you run `git commit`, Git simply package up these pre-de-duplicated, pre-frozen-formatted files *into* a new commit.  Git gathers the necessary and appropriate metadata from you and snapshots the files that are in the index / staging-area, and writes all that out as the new commit.  So what's in the *commit* is, necessarily, whatever *was* in the *index* at that time.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>The `git add` step will in fact *create* an object in the internal database if and as needed, so that it's ready to go.  If you wind up abandoning this—not making a commit from it—that object becomes *unreferenced* and Git eventually cleans it up later.  This is normally quite invisible, but if you accidentally add a 2 terabyte file on a drive that only holds a few terabytes, it can become a problem.

<sup>5</sup>Note that `git commit -a`, `git commit --include`, and `git commit --only` all work by *adding files to* some index.  The exact details depend on which of these options you use: some require creating one or even two extra, temporary index files.  The point here is that you can and should view them as running `git add`, to copy files into some index, then using `git commit` with this index.  The extra index files happen only so that they can get their jobs done *and* either roll back or forward to a new standard index, as if you'd run `git add` yourself or not, depending on whether the new commit works.  So even if you use these options, there's still a `git add` step happening.

---

#### Copying to and from your working tree files

Now, let's note *how* files go from a commit, to Git's index, to your working tree:

1. commit ⟶ index: no changes: still frozen and compressed/de-duplicated;
2. index ⟶ work-tree: **changed**!  Unfrozen, uncompressed, and normal file now!

Once you've modified some file *in* your working tree, you run `git add` on it:

1. work-tree ⟶ index: **changed**!  Frozen-formatted by compressing and de-duplicating.

Eventually, you run `git commit`, which takes what's in the index and wraps it up into a *new* commit.  The existing commits are all untouched.  The *new* commit points back to the existing commit.  For instance, if we have something like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

with the attached `(HEAD)` notation meaning that we're "on" branch `dev` and using commit `I`, and we make a *new* commit, we get a new commit `J` whose parent is `I`, and our name `dev` now selects our new commit `J`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

The files *in* the new commit `J` are those that were in Git's index when we ran `git commit`.  Those contain either the data from commit `I`, or some updated version written by running `git add`.

**Note that extracting the file changed it, and so did writing the file.**  The copies in the index were and are in the de-duplicated Git-ized format.  The copies in your working tree, where you can see and work on them, are not.  **This copying is the time when we can do things like line-ending changes.**

This copying already has to happen.  Suppose, then, that we'd *like* to have CRLF line endings in our working tree copies of files.  All we have to do is make sure that:

1. Copies *from* index *to* working-tree (all of them, though they mostly happen from `git checkout`) turn `\n` to `\r\n`, so that LF-line files become CRLF-line files.
2. Copies *from* working-tree *to* index (all of them, though they only happen from `git add` or the add step built into special options like `git commit -a`) turn `\r\n` into `\n`, so that CRLF-line files become LF-line files.

There are some problems though.  In particular, this kind of modification sometimes *damages* binary files.  For instance, JPG images can have byte sequences that are wrecked by such an update.  So we'd like to do this on *text* files only.

Setting `core.autocrlf` tells Git several things:

- First, Git should now *guess* which files are text files and which ones are binary files.  It should only do any line-ending modification on *text* files.
- Second, Git should now *guess* what kind of line endings *you* want in your work-tree files.

Some people like it when naïve programs like Git guess this sort of thing.  As you might infer from my use of the word "naïve", I don't.  The problem is more in the first bullet point: Git's decision as to whether something is text or binary isn't so great.  I think it has been improved since Git 1.5, but since I don't use it, I don't keep track.  Git's guess in terms of the second bullet point is probably almost always spot-on, though again, I don't really use it.

If we really do want this sort of action, though, we can do better: we can *tell Git which files need what done to them*.  We do this with the `.gitattributes` file.  This file goes into every commit—just like any file—and it contains lines, so it's a text file that should get modified, and then we can tell Git exactly what kind of line endings it should have in our work-tree.

The Git repository for Git has a `.gitattributes` file. Here's what is in it:

```
$ cat .gitattributes
* whitespace=!indent,trail,space
*.[ch] whitespace=indent,trail,space diff=cpp
*.sh whitespace=indent,trail,space eol=lf
*.perl eol=lf diff=perl
*.pl eof=lf diff=perl
*.pm eol=lf diff=perl
*.py eol=lf diff=python
*.bat eol=crlf
/Documentation/**/*.txt eol=lf
/command-list.txt eol=lf
/GIT-VERSION-GEN eol=lf
/mergetools/* eol=lf
/t/oid-info/* eol=lf
/Documentation/git-merge.txt conflict-marker-size=32
/Documentation/gitk.txt conflict-marker-size=32
/Documentation/user-manual.txt conflict-marker-size=32
/t/t????-*.sh conflict-marker-size=32
```

Note that although the documentation `*.txt` files are text, they're marked as `eol=lf`, so they will have LF-only line endings in any work-tree, even on Windows.  If, however, you're on a system where your own text editor *change* this to CRLF endings, Git will convert these files back to LF-only endings during `git add`, correcting the issue.

Meanwhile the `*.bat` files will have CRLF endings in any work-tree, even on Linux.  They will be changed back to LF-only endings by `git add`, and any file that has LF-only line endings inside the *repository* gets changed back to CRLF-endings during extraction.

You don't have to use these methods, but you *do* need to understand that Git does the conversions on the copies to or from your working tree files, from or to Git's index / staging-area copies.  You *can't* see, directly, what's in a commit, nor what's in Git's index, due to these various adjustments as files get copied in or out.  The only way to see what's *really* in Git's index, or in some commit, is to turn off all modifications, extract the file afresh—remove the working tree copy first to be sure—and then use a program that you know doesn't "fix" any "broken" (not really broken) work-tree copy, to examine the extracted copy.<sup>6</sup>

This is really just a specific case of the general problem of working with something that shows you some kind of projection or shadow of some underlying reality—a long-established problem in metaphysics, but one that I think most computer science / informatics people don't think about as often as they should.  See, e.g., [Could reality be a projection of another reality?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/59469)

---

<sup>6</sup>There are a few other methods involving programs that know how to read internal Git objects.  The main one is `git cat-file`, which can dump a pretty-printed internal object to stdout.  You can make sure it does not apply any text conversions by using it to examine an internal blob object by its hash ID.

Comment: This is a too long answer for me.  Can't you put in a 'tl;dr' at top and just give your best advice?  I don't want to make a living as a Git expert, I just need to fix the problem that some Windows teammates insert "^M" inadvertently.

Comment: @pauljohn32: simple recipes *will* fail, but here's your simple recipe: (1) never turn on `core.autocrlf` (2) create a `.gitattributes` file with explicit `text eol=lf` or `text eol=crlf` or `binary` for every file, so that it has the desired line endings when checked out, but is stored in the repository with lf-only line endings.