# Will MD5 ever return the same output as its input?

Tags: md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an MD5 Fixed Point where md5(x) == x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235785/is-there-an-md5-fixed-point-where-md5x-x)

What is the probability that md5 will return its input (i.e. the output will equal the input), or will it ever?