# Is it possible for the MD5 hash of a string to be the original string itself?

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5

For example, I have a string `s` and the MD5 of `s` is `m`. So is it possible for `s=m`.

Now it can be found by iterating through all possible combinations but there are `2^128` combinations to check through and I do not have the resources to do so. Is any such case possible and if it is possible then what is the case?

Comment: Why do you think there are `36^32` (about `6,3 * 10^49`)  combinations? MD5 has 128 bit therefore the number of possible values is `2^128` (about `3,4 * 10^38`). You see, your number is way too large...

Comment: MD5 has 32 characters [0-9a-z] therefore 36^32. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, MD5 has 128 bit and one character has 8 bit. Therefore you can have 128/8 = 16 characters. Also 36 is wrong as you have more than 36 printable ASCII characters.

Comment: `hashalg(x) = x` is called a *Fixed Point*, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235785/is-there-an-md5-fixed-point-where-md5x-x / http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19578/is-it-possible-to-demonstrate-that-md5x-x-for-any-x

Comment: To clear it up: MD5 returns 128bit values, so you get 2^128 possible combinations. It is usually represented [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), so each byte results in 2 characters of the alphabet [0-9,a-f]. That makes 16^32 combinations which is exactly the same (about 3E38 combinations).