# Is possible to find a string that satisfy this condition?

Tags: php, security, cryptography, md5

```
$myStr = $_GET['myStr'];
if ($myStr == md5($myStr)) echo "ok\n";
```

I know there is a type jugglying in the code, but in my tests I couldn't find an input that satisfies the condition.

Comment: This the very basic thing you just need to do some research

Comment: md5, security and cryptography in the same list of tags is somewhat dangerous.... These days md5 should never be used for anything to do with security

Comment: Don't understand what you want. You forget a ")" after ther "md5($myStr)"

Comment: Fixed the code!

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235785/is-there-an-md5-fixed-point-where-md5x-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an MD5 Fixed Point where md5(x) == x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235785/is-there-an-md5-fixed-point-where-md5x-x)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot find that `myStr` value as it would come down to finding a (first degree) pre-image for MD5. Although MD5 has been broken for collision resistance, you should not be able to find a pre-image. More information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack).

I'm presuming there that your code amounts to finding `y = md5(y)`. `y = md5(x)` is a more general assumption and it is described in the Wikipedia article linked to above that it is impossible to find such `H(x)`, even for MD5.

---

That doesn't mean that you should use MD5. Please use SHA-256, SHA-512 or indeed one of the SHA-3 functions. Even if MD5 hasn't been broken that far, it has been broken enough not to be used anymore; "Attacks always get better; they never get worse."

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the beginning. I will provide an example so i may help you maybe understand better.

In the first line you have `$myStr = $_GET['myStr'];`
I will just assume you will get this variable from your url like this :

```
http://localhost/md5Project.php?myStr=test
```

This will give your variable $myStr the value "test".

Moving forward in your if statement you have:

```
if ($myStr == md5($myStr)
```

this will never be true because `$myStr` value is `"test"` and `md5($myStr)` value is `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6` so basically you compare 2 strings with values `"test"` and `"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6problem"` which will always lead to false.

Comment: Never be true?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235785/is-there-an-md5-fixed-point-where-md5x-x

Comment: @Progrock Yes **never** because among other things "test" is 4 bytes and MD5 output is 16 bytes: the two are different lengths so will never be equal.

Comment: @zaph OP never stipulated that the input would be 'test'.

Comment: No matter what the input is i explained in my answer why they will never match.

Comment: @Progrock The answer did and that is what you responded to.